# git - copy commit-msg hook when clone repository

Tags: git, githooks

I created a commit-msg hook in my remote repositories, but i have to manually copy it to local .git/hooks/ directory after clone the projects.

Is there any way to copy this hook to local repo at the moment of cloning?
Or any way to automate this task?

I want the hook to be copied without any intervention from the programmer, only with:

$ git clone server:/path

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git hooks : is there a clone hook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228065/git-hooks-is-there-a-clone-hook)

Comment: jubobs, i want the commit-msg hook to be copied in a transparent manner, without additional parameters to 'git clone'.

Comment: Then, the answer is that it's not possible; no with Git alone.

Comment: The specific question isn't identical, but the underlying question is: [is there a way to inject code into other people's repos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26786778/can-i-specify-git-config-values-in-a-repo/26787439#26787439)?

Comment: So.. I will try an alternative solution!

Thank you Jubobs and jthill!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $ git clone server:/path && scp -p -P portnumber userlogin@serverip:commit-msg-path cloning_project/.git/hooks/
```